# Is it possible to host a BIND server within the AWS EC2 infrastructure?

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, bind

So my question is if it's possible to set up a BIND server within the infrastructure of EC2. I got tired of paying for DNS services and wanted to try my hand at configuring my own BIND server, following this guide... https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/dns-configuration.html. As of now I have forwarder entries pointing to the OpenDNS name servers and master entries configured for the elastic IP that's associated with the EC2 instance. I'm pretty sure the reverse lookup entries are incorrect, as I pretty much followed that guide to the letter.

Any insight would be awesome.

Comment: Yes, its possible. You can even create more reliable and fast DNS network using different EC2 servers from different regions...

Comment: I figured out that my elastic IP had been unassociated, so DNS requests weren't even getting to the server. Thanks for the comment though, I kept at it until I figured it out.

Comment: This question needs one more vote before it's closed. There's no _real_ question here. If you run in to a problem with your setup later we'll be happy to help!